# html with lots of repetition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am making a code to see the "note of proof", but one would have to do this code until question 45, could not simplify ?, keeping in mind that the name and the data of h4 should rise linearly?

```
            <div class="radio">
            <h4> questao 1</h4>
                <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="Q1" value="A"> A <br></label>
                <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="Q1" value="B"> B <br></label>
                <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="Q1" value="C"> C <br></label>
                <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="Q1" value="D"> D <br></label>
                <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="Q1" value="E"> E <br></label>
            </div>
            <hr />
            <div class="radio">
                <h4> questao 2</h4>
                <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="Q2" value="A"> A <br></label>
                <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="Q2" value="B"> B <br></label>
                <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="Q2" value="C"> C <br></label>
                <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="Q2" value="D"> D <br></label>
                <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="Q2" value="E"> E <br></label>
                <hr />
            </div>
            <div class="radio">
                <h4> questao 3</h4>
                <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="Q3" value="A"> A <br></label>
                <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="Q3" value="B"> B <br></label>
                <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="Q3" value="C"> C <br></label>
                <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="Q3" value="D"> D <br></label>
                <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="Q3" value="E"> E <br></label>
                <hr />
            </div>
            <div class="radio">
                <h4> questao 4</h4>
                <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="Q4" value="A"> A <br></label>
                <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="Q4" value="B"> B <br></label>
                <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="Q4" value="C"> C <br></label>
                <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="Q4" value="D"> D <br></label>
                <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="Q4" value="E"> E <br></label>
                <hr />
            </div>
            <div class="radio">
                <h4> questao 5</h4>
                <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="Q5" value="A"> A <br></label>
                <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="Q5" value="B"> B <br></label>
                <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="Q5" value="C"> C <br></label>
                <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="Q5" value="D"> D <br></label>
                <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="Q5" value="E"> E <br></label>
                <hr />
            </div>
```

up to question 45

Comment: Take a look to the `for` loop in javascript...

Comment: A templating library might also be a good idea too, if you do this a lot.

Comment: You could use  a server side language to generate the page, ex. php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nested [for](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration) loops can solve this fairly easily.

```js
var numbersToLetters = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"];

//first for loop to generate question number
for (i = 1; i <= 45; i++) {
  $("#container").append("<div class='radio' id='" + i + "'></div><hr/>");
  $("div #" + i + "").append("<h4> questao " + i + "</h4>");

  //second for loop to generate possible answers
  for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
    $("div #" + i + "").append("<label class='radio-inline'><input type='radio' name='Q" + i + "' value='" + numbersToLetters[j] + "'/>" + numbersToLetters[j] + "</label><br/>");
  }

  //set first item of each radio group to checked by default
  $("input[name='Q" + i + "']").first().prop("checked", true);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: I made a mistake before, i was selecting on div.radio which was incorrect as it would select all generated divs with that class. To compensate I added a unique id for each and selected on that instead. Hope it helps

Comment: Input names will be a bit off

Comment: @Kiogara thats true, in the process of updating the answer

Comment: Answer updated should work fine now and provide unique names for each radio button group. Will even check each first item in a radio group by default.

Answer (score 0):

As this is a JavaScript Question my pure Solution:

```js
document.body.innerHTML = buildContent();

function buildContent(){
  var content ='';
  for (var i = 1; i <= 45; i++) {
    var radio = '<div class="radio">';
    var h4 = '<h4> questao '+i+'</h4>';
    var label ='';
    var char = nextChar('z');
    for( var i2 = 0; i2 <= 4; i2++) {
      var label_s = '<label class="radio-inline">';
      var input = '<input type="radio" name="Q'+i+'" value="'+char+'">';
      var label_e = char+' <br></label>';
      label += label_s+input+label_e;
      char = nextChar(char);
    }
    content += radio+h4+label;
  }
  return content;
}

function nextChar(c) {
  var i = (parseInt(c, 36) + 1 ) % 36;
  return (!i * 10 + i).toString(36).toUpperCase();
}
```